# Create a Bitmap in python

Tags: python, bitmap

I need to create a bitmap in python but I know:

- bitmap pixel values
- width
- height
- color planes
- bits per pixel

I've already tried using **PIL.Image** but it doesn't let you choose an arbitrary bpp value (for instance I need 4 bpp which is not present in the supported modes).

Answer (score 0):

If this is for fitting a maximum of information into available memory and you do not need display, load or save in a 4 bpp format that other applications can handle you could just use 8 bpp with half the width and wrap the two functions `getpixel()` and `putpixel()` to access or modify the respective halves of the 8 bits at `(x//2, y)`, i.e. `value >> 4` and `value & 15`, depending on whether `x & 1 == 0`. The function `paste()` can also easily be wrapped for `x & 1 == 0` and even width. For other `x` or odd width, `paste()` takes a bit of effort to shift the bits into the right positions. Similarly, 2 bpp can use `x//4`.

For bit depths that are not a power of 2, one will want to go with the greatest depth available, e.g. an 8 bpp pixel could only store 2 pixels with 3 bpp but 64 bpp could store 21 such pixels, improving efficiency by 31%.